# Angular2 authguards executing asynchronous functions fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to protect my routes by checking if a user is logged in from the server but the asynchronous functions don't get executed

This is my code:

```
canActivate (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot , state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  let permission = route.data[ "permission" ]; //permissions are set on the routes
   if(permission){
       ..execute another function which works
    )
  }else{
    return this.checkLogin()  //this one is the one that fails
  }
}
```

On the function `checkLogin`:

```
checkLogin (url?: string): any {
  this.authService.checkLoggedin()
    .subscribe(
      res=>{
       if(res){
         return true;
       }else{
          this.router.navigate ( [ '/login' ] );
          return false
       }

    }
  )
}
```

Now on the auth service

```
checkLoggedin():Observable<any> {
//check from server if user is loggdin
  return this._httpclient.get(this.authurl + "/default/is-loggedin")
    .map(res => {

        return res.json().data;
    },error=>{
      return Observable.of(false);
      }
    );
}
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: You are not returning a result from `checkLogin`. You need to change it to return an `Observable<boolean>` or `Promise<boolean>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkLogin` must return either an `Observable<boolean>` or a `Promise<boolean>` (or a plain `boolean` if it were synchronous). You aren't returning anything.

Try this. Instead of `subscribe` just use `map` to modify the value emitted by `checkLoggedin()` and then return the `Observable` with the appropriate boolean.

```
checkLogin (url?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.checkLoggedin()
    .map(
      res=>{
       if(res){
         return true;
       }else{
          this.router.navigate ( [ '/login' ] );
          return false
       }
    });
}
```

A good tip might also be to never declare a function as returning `any`, always declare it as the actual type you are returning and then the compiler can do its job and tell you if you forgot to return a result when you actually needed to return one.

Likewise `checkLoggedin():Observable<any>` should be `checkLoggedin():Observable<boolean>` to maximise the chance of catching errors (and you may have to do some conversion on the json data then to make it work).

Answer (score 0):

this.router.navigate() resolves to true when navigation successful so you are actually returning true.

https://angular.io/api/router/Router

you should actually do router.navigate in the else block of your canActivate method after the call to checklogin and based on its result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let permission = route.data[ "permission" ]; //permissions are set on the routes
       return !permission ? true : this.checkLoggedin()
                    .map((res: any) => {
                        if (res) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        throw new Error('Not logged in!');
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        return Observable.of(false);
                    });
            }
```