# Angular 2 Router Events: Is it possible to wait for AJAX response before the next event is executed?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code that performs an AJAX request during the `NavigationStart` event of the router.

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {

        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            // PERFORM AJAX CALL HERE
        }

    });
```

What I want to achieve is to wait for the AJAX response before the next event is triggered. Is this possible?

Comment: no, router doesn't expect any output from events

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What is the purpose?

Comment: Maybe, but just maybe this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697307/angular2-authguards-executing-asynchronous-functions-fails can help you. The user in this case uses guards and want to do a ajax call